# std::map order of insertions and performance

Tags: c++, sorting, stdmap

If I'd like to load relatively huge file of pairs <string-key, int-value> and use std::map for storing the data. When I load each entry one by one and insert it to the map the insertion operation will take O(log N). I'd like to improve this by ordering entries in the file to make sure that when I load each entry one by one form the file the insertion will take exactly single iteration. This could potentaially be achieved by providing right orger of entries in the file. The question is what would be the order? Is it right to assume that the same order as the map is sorted is correct? I use standard comparison method for strings as std::map does by default.

Comment: if you can sort the entries before and if the keys are already unique then there is maybe no need for the `std::map` in the first place. You can use a `std::vector< std::pair<std::string,int>>`

Comment: not clear what exactly you mean with this "...to make sure that when I load each entry one by one form the file the insertion will take exactly single iteration."

Comment: `std::map` is probably a red-black tree but there's no guarantee, any insertion order would be standard library implementation specific

Comment: If you insert the elements in order you can use insert/emplace with a hint where to place to value (at the end), then you have constant complexity guaranteed.

Comment: Note overloads for [insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) there is `pos` parameter to give a hint were element should go. If data in file are sorted using `end()` iterator will work fine. Presorting in a `std::vector` most probably will be pointless. Please measure that to make sure.

Comment: Do not assume anything write benchmark test and measure each possible implementation. Be aware that writing good perforce test is tricky since optimizer can outsmart you.

Comment: C++23 is giving us `std::flat_map`, which has constructors that takes a `std::sorted_unique_t` marker, and the values, which must be sorted and unique under pain of undefined behaviour. They are linear if copying, or constant if moving

Comment: @Caleth Is it better than `map`'s linear-time constructors? (I'm no C++ person, can't really judge them.)

Comment: @KellyBundy probably the same. The `map` ones fall back to being superlinear if the input isn't sorted

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you have an sequence of pairs in `value_comp()` order, you can use [the 4th overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map)

```
template< class InputIt >
map(InputIt first, InputIt last);
```

This is required to take linear time if the sequence is sorted in `value_comp()` order.

Comment: From my benchmarks looks like this overload performance sucks (for gcc and clang). See other answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in comments:

> Note overloads for [insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) there is `pos` parameter to give a hint were element should go. If data in file are sorted using `end()` iterator will work fine. Presorting in a `std::vector` most probably will be pointless.

> Do not assume anything write benchmark test and measure each possible implementation. Be aware that writing good perforce test is tricky since optimizer can outsmart you.

When dealing with performance first rule is measure fust, secodn rule is measure first, third rule is ... .

First measurement which should be done is profiling your code. Aim is to find leading bottle necks in code. It is waste of time to optimize code which runs for 10% of time.

In second step you should measure how modification of code impacts performance. There might be many surprises which could lead to worse results.

So in your case benchmarks could look like this, **Tweak those test so they match your use case more precisely. **This is very important see bellow.

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

constexpr size_t DataSizeStart = 8 << 10;
constexpr size_t DataSizeStop = 8 << 10;

using TestData = std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>;
using TestDataConst = std::vector<std::pair<const std::string, int>>;

std::string makeStringFor(size_t x)
{
  std::ostringstream out;
  out << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(6) << x;
  return out.str();
}

TestData sortedData(size_t n)
{
  TestData r;
  r.reserve(n);
  size_t i = 0;
  std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(r), n, [&i]() {
    return std::pair{makeStringFor(++i), i};
  });
  return r;
}

TestData shuffledData(size_t n)
{
  auto data = sortedData(n);
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 g(rd());

  std::shuffle(data.begin(), data.end(), g);
  return data;
}

TestDataConst sortedConstData(size_t n)
{
  auto r = sortedData(n);
  return {r.begin(), r.end()};
}

TestDataConst shuffledConstData(size_t n)
{
  auto r = shuffledData(n);
  return {r.begin(), r.end()};
}

template<auto Data>
static void CreateMapInsert(benchmark::State& state) {
  auto n = state.range(0);
  auto data = Data(n);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(data);
    std::map<std::string, int> m;

    for (auto& p : data) {
      m.insert(m.end(), p);
    }
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(m);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(CreateMapInsert<sortedData>)->RangeMultiplier(2)->Range(DataSizeStart, DataSizeStop);
BENCHMARK(CreateMapInsert<shuffledData>)->RangeMultiplier(2)->Range(DataSizeStart, DataSizeStop);
BENCHMARK(CreateMapInsert<sortedConstData>)->RangeMultiplier(2)->Range(DataSizeStart, DataSizeStop);
BENCHMARK(CreateMapInsert<shuffledConstData>)->RangeMultiplier(2)->Range(DataSizeStart, DataSizeStop);

template<auto Data>
static void CreateMapDirectly(benchmark::State& state) {
  auto n = state.range(0);
  auto data = Data(n);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(data);
    std::map<std::string, int> m{data.begin(), data.end()};
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(m);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(CreateMapDirectly<sortedData>)->RangeMultiplier(2)->Range(DataSizeStart, DataSizeStop);
BENCHMARK(CreateMapDirectly<shuffledData>)->RangeMultiplier(2)->Range(DataSizeStart, DataSizeStop);
BENCHMARK(CreateMapDirectly<sortedConstData>)->RangeMultiplier(2)->Range(DataSizeStart, DataSizeStop);
BENCHMARK(CreateMapDirectly<shuffledConstData>)->RangeMultiplier(2)->Range(DataSizeStart, DataSizeStop);

template<auto Data>
static void FirstSortVectorThenCreateMapDirctly(benchmark::State& state) {
  auto n = state.range(0);
  auto data = Data(n);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(data);
    auto sorted = data;
    std::sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end());
    std::map<std::string, int> m{sorted.begin(), sorted.end()};
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(m);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(FirstSortVectorThenCreateMapDirctly<shuffledData>)->RangeMultiplier(2)->Range(DataSizeStart, DataSizeStop);

template<auto Data>
static void FirstSortVectorThenMapIsert(benchmark::State& state) {
  auto n = state.range(0);
  auto data = Data(n);
  for (auto _ : state) {
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(data);
    auto sorted = data;
    std::sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end());
    std::map<std::string, int> m;
    
    for (auto& p : sorted) {
      m.insert(m.end(), p);
    }
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(m);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(FirstSortVectorThenMapIsert<shuffledData>)->RangeMultiplier(2)->Range(DataSizeStart, DataSizeStop);
```

Table of results

| compiler | comparing different data sizes | samples 8192 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| gcc 12.2 | [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/HP0rFcHucQllJd-6AP9ygF12bq8) | [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/iqi_WcS82e2xeDO-c1R1Kkp-Rq8) |
| clang 15 libstdc++ | [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/rjzFyD-Or9iPlUbOl56hI6DrQuc) | [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/jqHhE9K55sO7DIeXUtSV96kmJAs) |
| clang 14 libc++ | [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/UERuwO0zaL9CjP_jxzepgzwkKpU) | [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/VR2cNJjoj7YOAVKl3Q10aljJBxU) |

In general case data should be added by `insert` with `pos` since in all scenarios gives best results (or near best).

This also proves that sorting data in `std::vector` first is doesn't give significant gains comparing to other slow methods. In case of clang and libc++ it is slowest solution.

I'm also surprised that constructing map directly from iterators to `std::<std::string, in>` performs so poorly. As `Caleth` caught comment below adding `const` to `std::pair<const std::string, int>` saves the day. In this case constructor becomes fastest choice.

Not that apparently `stdlibc++` is has some performance bug, `libc++` is faster in this scenario and do not have this strange behavior for missing `const` in a pair. `libc++` is fastest for both versions of pair.

I've filed [respective bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=109022) for gcc libstd++.

Comment: What's the x-axis in those charts? The number of elements? It only goes up to 128.

Comment: size of data, note `->RangeMultiplier(2)->Range(8, 8<<4);` and `auto n = state.range(0);` for each test.

Comment: If to large vales are feed then site will timeout tests and will not provide results.

Comment: @MarekR: In MSVC, the hint parameter is 100% ignored, so I'm surprised to see that it's faster than pre-sorted input here.

Comment: @MooingDuck Didn't run those benchmarks on MSVC, and link provided for gcc and clang proves that insertion hint is not ignored for this compilers.

Comment: I wonder why `CreateMapDirectlyFormSortedData` seems relatively slow...

Comment: @KellyBundy me too. It is even slower to scenario where inserting shuffled data.

Comment: It looks to be because you are testing `std::pair<std::string, int>`, not `std::pair<const std::string, int>`. If you fix that, iterator constructor becomes quicker: https://quick-bench.com/q/4NGYB7i-toKw_j-GVaoV8-fUMhA.

Comment: @Caleth good catch. Still this is weird this `const` is so important. Conversion between those two pairs should not have such big impact. There must be something extra underneath.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't bother to try inserting in order if `iterator_value_t<Iter>` is different to `value_type`

Comment: At 64, I see vector being 36% slower. At 128, it's already only 24% slower. How do you know vector won't catch up or become *faster* for their "relatively huge" data?

Comment: Did some refactoring and run for 8192 data size: https://quick-bench.com/q/OikGI9shga5OH3XgyEj7OZHbd10 at such size all possible cache misses should already be active. vector solution losses heavily.

Comment: Better. Still wondering why vector is so slow. Takes 2 times as long as the slow direct map builders? If I remove its map building, it's only about 0.5 times as long as them. So its map building part takes 1.5 times as long as the the others? That seems weird. And could its map building part be sped up (const-casting the vector-iterators or so?) to be as fast as the fast direct map builders, so that the vector solution only takes 0.5+0.2=0.7 times as long as the slow direct map builders? I'd try it, but am not good with C++ and that website is almost unusable on a phone.

Comment: Wait... Am I mistaken, or is that vector one putting the values into the map **twice**? Once via constructor, once via insert-loop?

Comment: https://quick-bench.com/q/TCFp4VOz4j0egZ8iFCo39cQTv7w